# simple dagger unit test fails

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I'm new to dagger.  I created a very simply unit test to try to understand how I should use dagger.  Unfortunately it fails.  I've probably not understood some basic principles of dagger.

```
public class A {
    @Inject
    public B b;

    public B getB() {
      return b;
    }
}

public class B {
}

@Module(injects = { A.class, B.class })
public class DaggerModule {
    @Provides
    public A provideA() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Provides
    public B provideB() {
         return new B();
    }
}
```

and my test class which fails

```
public class DaggerTest extends TestCase {
    public void testDagger() {
        ObjectGraph theGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new DaggerModule());
        A theA = theGraph.get(A.class);
        assertNotNull(theA.getB());
    }
}
```

I thought that dagger would inject B into A since A wants it to be injected and DaggerModule contains a @Provides annotated method which creates B.

Update:

I found that when I write the module class like this

```
@Module(injects = { A.class })
public class DaggerModule {
    @Provides
    public B provideB() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

the injection of B into A works.  However I do not understand why it is not working when the module has a Provides annotated method which construct an instance of A.  In that case the only way to get the injection to work is to actually write the injection yourself like:

```
@Module(injects = { A.class, B.class })
public class DaggerModule {
    @Provides
    public A provideA(B b) {
        A theA =  new A();
        theA.b = b;
        return theA;
    }

    @Provides
    public B provideB() {
         return new B();
    }
}
```

or to create a constructor in A which accepts B so that you can write

```
@Module(injects = { A.class, B.class })
public class DaggerModule {
    @Provides
    public A provideA(B b) {
        return new A(b);
    }

    @Provides
    public B provideB() {
         return new B();
    }
}
```

This need for having a constructor or setter in A which accepts B was just the kind of overhead I thought could by avoided by using Dagger.

So I'm I doing something wrong or did I misinterpreted the capabilities of dagger?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed exactly the same behaviour, i.e. @Provides produced instances don't get their @Inject marked members injected. cf [Dagger & nested injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652997/dagger-nested-injections)

I did exactly the same as you: use @Provides parameters injection to forward to the constructor (without the same impression that it kind of defeats dagger's purpose). I'll try to dive a bit more into dagger to figure out if this is a normal behaviour as soon I have some spare time.

Answer (score 0):

If you make Class A the entry point of your module than dagger will inject dependecy B to A.

```
@Module(entryPoints = { A.class })
public class DaggerModule {
    @Provides
    public A provideA() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Provides
    public B provideB() {
         return new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like 'entryPoints' has been renamed to 'injects' since version 1.0.0. so I've written '@Module(injects = { A.class })'  But still B is not injected into A.

Comment: According to your sample code you do not need to set B as "injects". Did you tried constructor injection?