# Activity graphs and non-found dependency

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I'm starting using the dagger, like it pretty much, but now facing some difficulties. My scenario is as follows: there's an activity and a dependency for it. Dependency is injected to the activity, and requires a reference to that activity. Just like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {        
    @Inject ScbeHelper scbeHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }
}

public class ScbeHelper {

    protected static final String TAG = "scbe_helper";  
    private BaseActivity activityContext;

    @Inject 
    public ScbeHelper(BaseActivity context) {       
        this.activityContext = context;
    }
}
```

I'm following [dagger's example from the github](https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs) for activity's graphs. So I've created a similar structure in my project. First, the `BaseActivity` class, from which `MainActivity` is inherited:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private ObjectGraph activityGraph;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        protoApp application = (protoApp) getApplication();
        // Exception happens in next line, inside plus() method
        activityGraph = application.getApplicationGraph().plus(getModules().toArray());

        // Inject ourselves so subclasses will have dependencies fulfilled when this method returns.
        activityGraph.inject(this);

        ((protoApp)getApplication()).inject(this);
    }

    protected List<Object> getModules() {
        return Arrays.<Object>asList(new ActivityModule(this));
    }

    public void inject(Object object) {
        activityGraph.inject(object);
    }
}
```

And the module:

```
@Module(injects={MainActivity.class})
public class ActivityModule {
    private final BaseActivity activity;

    public ActivityModule(BaseActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton BaseActivity provideActivity() {
        return activity;        
    }   
}
```

**Now, the problem:** `No injectable members on com.example.proto.BaseActivity. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by public com.example.proto.ScbeHelper(com.example.proto.BaseActivity)`

In other words, provider method `ActivityModule.provideActivity()` doesn't really provide the instance of `BaseActivity` for some reason, though in my understanding it's set up correctly. Does anyone see an error in my setup? Am I missing something in dagger's logic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Dagger expert, but you have 2 issues:

- you have a cyclical dependency: you helper want to have the activity injected, your activity wants to have the helper injected. I don't think Dagger can resolve this
- your activity tries to get injected twice, once with the activity-level graph, once with the application-level graph

Here's what I did to get it to work:

- in ScbeHelper: remove the @Inject annotation
- in BaseActivity: remove ((protoApp)getApplication()).inject(this);
- in ActivityModule: remove your provideActivity method (it's not going to be used anymore), and add the following method:

```java
@Provides @Singleton ScbeHelper provideScbeHelper() {
    return new ScbeHelper(activity);
}
```

What this does is it provides your ScbeHelper with the context it needs, but leaves only 1 annotation-driven injection so dagger can resolve it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention why I removed the application-level graph in your activity: in fact your activity is not an entry-point to the AndroidModule, only to the ActivityModule, therefore you cannot inject it using this graph, only the activity-level graph